# Add Static Library to Contiki Makefile. File Format Not Recognized

Tags: c++, c, makefile, contiki

I have a simple contiki project, and have linked it with a simple static library created with eclipse project located in a separated directory.This is my makefile.

```
CONTIKI_PROJECT = hello-eclipse
all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)
LIBINCLUDE = /home/farissyariati/Software/Contiki/contiki-2.7/contiki-projects/ContikiExampleStaticLib/
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBINCLUDE)
PROJECT_LIBRARIES += /home/farissyariati/Software/Contiki/contiki-2.7/contiki-projects/ContikiExampleStaticLib/Release/libContikiExampleStaticLib.a

CONTIKI = ../..
include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

And this is my c file.

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "calculate.h"
#include <stdio.h>

PROCESS(hello_eclipse_process, "Hello Eclipse Process");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&hello_eclipse_process);

PROCESS_THREAD(hello_eclipse_process, ev, data){
    PROCESS_BEGIN();
    int x = add_something(1, 2);
    printf("Hello Eclipse %d\n", x);
    PROCESS_END();
}
```

After trying several way to link my static library with makefile, I successfully build it on my eclipse, but when I build it in my cooja to add a new mote, the cooja inform me something like this

```
/home/farissyariati/Software/Contiki/contiki-2.7/contiki-projects/ContikiExampleStaticLib/Release/libContikiExampleStaticLib.a: could not read symbols: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello-eclipse.z1] Error 1
rm obj_z1/contiki-z1-main.o hello-eclipse.co
Process returned error code 2
```

How can I fix it? I have dealt with it for a week. 
Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to say for sure.  For example, we need to see the command line make invoked when building your program (the one that returned the error) and the command line used to create the static library.  But based on the info here I'd say the static library was built incorrectly: it may be named `libContikiExampleStaticLib.a` but it's not really an archive.  If you run `file .../libContikiExampleStaticLib.a`, what does it say?

Comment: You need to compile with V=1 otherwise it's a black-box.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. But the problem is, I using cooja to build the application. Do you know how to change the make command

Comment: Also, I tried to use this one on my eclipse, so I do not need to build from cooja.

make TARGET=z1 V=1

/home/farissyariati/Software/Contiki/contiki-2.7/contiki-projects/ContikiExampleSharedLib/Release/libContikiExampleSharedLib.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello-eclipse.z1] Error 1
rm obj_z1/contiki-z1-main.o hello-eclipse.co